# Secure HereMaps keys

Tags: android, here-maps-rest

I am using the HereMaps API to develop mobile applications. More specifically, I am using the REST API and not the Mobile SDK to carry my task.

Since I have to embed the App Id and App Code in the request, it makes it insecure as anyone can just take those 2 informations and use them for their own purposes.

I would like to know if it's possible on the HereMaps dashboard or any other means to restrict the calls only from my mobile apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can lock the credential to one or several domains.
 This is possible from developer.here.com portal, for each of your projects